# Rename files in folder with various extensions according to worksheet list

Tags: excel, vba

I need to rename 300+ files of various extensions in 1 folder. I have a list of file names without extension in column B, and final names in column A of my Excel worksheet. My code works, but renames files in wrong order. Filenames contain dots, like

> А1.14.12.2016

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test2()
    Dim x As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim oldPath As String
    Dim newPath As String
    Dim i As Long

    oldPath = "\\Plu20\dfs01\USMiKAR\docs\"
    newPath = oldPath & "New\"
    On Error Resume Next
    x = GetAttr(newPath) And 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MkDir newPath
    fName = Dir(oldPath & "*.*")
    With ActiveSheet
        Do While Len(fName) > 0
            i = i + 1
            FileCopy oldPath & fName, newPath & .Cells(i, 1) & Mid$(fName, InStrRev(fName, "."))
            '.Cells(i, 2) = oldPath & fName 'ïðîâåðêà
            'Kill oldPath & fName 'óäàëåíèå ñòàðûõ
            fName = Dir
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `On Error Resume Next` makes you blind for any errors. Never use it like that. Always use a complete error handling [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Can you please specify in your question what does *"renames files in wrong order"* exactly mean? Give an example please.

Comment: for example, 1st file is "А1.14.12.2016.pdf", and it should be renamed as "1-А1.14.12.2016.pdf", and after rename I see file "1-А1.14.12.2016.doc", and its another file(

Comment: There's no guaranteee what order the files are enumerated using Dir() - you will need to check each file's name to determine what the new name should be.  You can do that by looking up the name in ColB and taking the new name from ColA

Comment: so, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but you can do something like this:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim x As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim oldPath As String
    Dim newPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fso As Object, f As Range

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    oldPath = "\\Plu20\dfs01\USMiKAR\docs\"
    newPath = oldPath & "New\"

    If Dir(newPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir newPath

    fName = Dir(oldPath & "*.*")
    With ActiveSheet
        Do While Len(fName) > 0
            'find the current filename
            Set f = .Columns(2).Find(fso.getbasename(fName), lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                'got a match
                FileCopy oldPath & fName, _
                   newPath & f.Offset(0, -1).Value & "." & fso.getextensionname(fName)
                '.Cells(i, 2) = oldPath & fName 'ïðîâåðêà
                'Kill oldPath & fName 'óäàëåíèå ñòàðûõ
            Else
                'no match...
                Debug.Print "filename:" & fName & " was not matched"
            End If

            fName = Dir
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```